# Can I change the sort order of labels in evolution?

Tags: evolution, tags

In Evolution an email can be labeled by selecting from a pop-up menu. New items can be added right there on the menu. The new label is then added to the bottom of the list.

I would like to re-order my labels (or at least have them sorted alphabetically), but haven't been able to find a way to to this.

I am using Evolution 2.22.3.1 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are stored in ~/.gconf/apps/evolution/mail/%gconf.xml.  Here's the defaults, plus 1:

```
<entry name="labels" mtime="1254501809" type="list" ltype="string">
        <li type="string">
                <stringvalue>I_mportant:#EF2929|$Labelimportant</stringvalue>
        </li>
        <li type="string">
                <stringvalue>_Work:#F57900|$Labelwork</stringvalue>
        </li>
        <li type="string">
                <stringvalue>_Personal:#4E9A06|$Labelpersonal</stringvalue>
        </li>
        <li type="string">
                <stringvalue>_To Do:#3465A4|$Labeltodo</stringvalue>
        </li>
        <li type="string">
                <stringvalue>_Later:#75507B|$Labellater</stringvalue>
        </li>
        <li type="string">
                <stringvalue>_Junk:#42b2adbc5aa4|_junk</stringvalue>
        </li>
</entry>
```

I added junk from within the evolution preferences window.  When I add an entry manually here, or when I change the order of the entries, they appear to be overwritten by something.  Even changing the 'mtime' attribute - the attruibute gets reset to it's 'pre edited by me' value.

Using gconftool-2:

```
gconftool-2 --dump /apps/evolution > mail-prefs.xml
```

edit the xml file in your favorite text editor. Then:

```
gconftool-2 --load mail-prefs.xml
```

This worked for me on ubuntu 9.05, evolution 2.26.1